# Why does this XF86 keybind cause my laptop to hang?

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad W530 running Archlabs. I've just moved to a new ssd so I'm editing my configs.

On the previous ssd, I made it so that when I pressed my ThinkVantage button it would play random audio files from a given folder.

~/.config/openbox/rc.xml:

```
   <keybind key="XF86Launch1">
       <action name="Execute">
               <command>~/bin/thinkvantage.sh</command>
     </action>
     </keybind>
```

~/bin/thinkvantage.sh:

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash
   # Play random sound. Triggered when ThinkVantage button is pressed.
   mpv $(shuf -n1 -e /home/korgan/audio/sound_effects/ThinkVantage/*) --volume=100
```

This used to work on the previous ssd, but now: it'll play the sound, but then my keyboard will stop working, everything hangs, and I have to reboot.

I think I remember on the previous setup, that there was more to getting the ThinkVantage button to work, but I can't remember what it might have been.

To be more specific: the ThinkVantage button will work when I press it, it will work if I press it again too. I can press alt+tab to switch windows; the task switcher will appear on the screen but it won't actually switch to anything. I can get my rofi shutdown menu to appear to and that way I can reboot. Other than that, nothing works. If I try to switch to a terminal and type, nothing appears.

**EDIT**
I never figured this out, but I replaced mpv with ffplay and now everything works. I don't know what it was about the mpv line that caused openbox to hang. Here's the new script:

```
# play random sound. Triggered when ThinkVantage button is pressed.
# config in .config/openbox/rc.xml
ffplay $(shuf -n1 -e /home/korgan/audio/sound_effects/ThinkVantage/*) -nodisp -autoexit
```

I'd still like to know what the problem was.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you run the script manually?

Comment: No. Only when I press the button.